# Collection view. Кастомные ячейки

Tags: swift, xcode, коллекции, uicollectionview

Передо мной поставлена задача, создать несколько кастомных collection view cell.

Каждая из них должна быть определенного размера и содержать абсолютно разную информацию.

в одной должны быть заголовки на подобии "модель" "год" "стоимость"

во второй "дата покупки" "адрес" 
в третьей "находиться ли в розыске аппарат"

Я создал несколько ячеек и заполнил по ТЗ. но когда я подключил их collectionViewDataSours/delegate у меня продублировала первая несколько раз.

как создать независимые друг от друга ячейки, и чтоб при изменении в interface builder правки не касались других?

сейчас я использую

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return summaryScrollViewCell.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ceel", for: indexPath)
        as?gosRegisterTopCollectionViewCell

        cell?.labelTest.text = summaryScrollViewCell[indexPath.row]
        return cell!
    }
```

как реализовать задуманное?

Comment: Добрый день, у каждой ячейки должен быть свой Identifier, и свой класс, а вы при инициализации используете только этот gosRegisterTopCollectionViewCell.

Comment: я создал для каждой ячейки свой класс и идентификатор. как их инициализировать в коде теперь?

можете показать пример кода?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так будет выглядеть инициализация ячеек по порядку. (если будет 4тая ячейка она будет выглядеть как третья)

```
class TableViewCellOne: UICollectionViewCell {
  let identifier = "One"
}

class TableViewCellTwo: UICollectionViewCell {
  let identifier = "Two"
}

class TableViewCellThree: UICollectionViewCell {
  let identifier = "Three"
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

  var cell: UICollectionViewCell!

  switch indexPath.row {
  case 1:
    cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "One", for: indexPath)
      as? TableViewCellOne
  case 2:
    cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Two", for: indexPath)
      as? TableViewCellTwo
  default:
    cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Three", for: indexPath)
      as? TableViewCellThree
  }

  return cell

}
```

Соответственно в каждом кейсе прописываете параметры каждой ячейки.

P/S `identifier` надо приписывать в Storyboard, (или там где мы создателе ячейку)

Comment: добавил все как Вы предложили. Но теперь выводится только 3я ячейка, как и прописано в параметре     default:

Остальные ячейки не отображаются.
В чем может заключаться проблема?

Comment: Пройдите дебагером этот метод.

Comment: А так-же в этом методе распечатайте indexPath, скорее всего у вас несколько секций.

Comment: Разобрался в чем была проблема.

В строке

`extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return 1`

После исправления на 3 - все ячейки стали отображаться. Но третья почему-то идет первой. Порядок ячеек теперь 3 - 1 - 2. 
Разбираюсь в чем проблема. 

Виктор, Спасибо Вам за помощь